# The type of the element stored in Mat structure of OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, types, mat

Does there exist some methods that I can use to determine the data type(such as uchar,cv::Vec3b...)of the element stored in Mat structure in OpenCV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cv::Mat::type()` to determine the data type of pixels stored in the `cv::Mat`.

The type can be determined as follows:

```
int type = mat.type();
if(type == CV_8UC1)
    unsigned char* ptr = mat.ptr<unsigned char>();
else if(type == CV_8UC3)
    cv::Vec3b* ptr = mat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>();
else if(type == CV_16UC3)
    unsigned short* ptr = mat.ptr<unsigned short>();
else if(type == CV_16UC3)
    cv::Vec3w* ptr = mat.ptr<cv::Vec3w>();
else if(type == CV_32FC1)
    float* ptr = mat.ptr<float>();
else if(type == CV_32FC3)
    cv::Vec3f* ptr = mat.ptr<cv::Vec3f>();
else
    printf("Unknown type\n");
```

Comment: THe problem is that ptr, defined that way, is visible only inside if statment.

Comment: @old-ufo.. Yes I was just trying to clear the concept using an example. A union or something like that can be used to avoid this problem.